# remove duplicate value from multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have csv file, i am reading data from it, i have join all which are randomly matching their rows like brands, customer and soon..,

Here i want to remove all duplicate from multi dimensional array which already in array

Here you can see how all duplicate values are appending to array:
[image]

Here is my php code

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($csv);
//exit;
$brand =[];
foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
    if(!(in_array($value[14], $brand))){
    $brand[$value[21]]['brands'][]=$value[14];    
    $brand[$value[21]]['products'][]=$value[1];    
    }   
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($brand);
```

Thanks and welcome for all suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify where you are looking in the `in_array`. You want to do this for both I'm sure, as well as check that it is set first:

```
foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($brand[$value[21]]['brands']) ||
       !in_array($value[14], $brand[$value[21]]['brands'])){
            $brand[$value[21]]['brands'][]=$value[14];
    }
    if(!isset($brand[$value[21]]['products']) ||
       !in_array($value[14], $brand[$value[21]]['products'])){
            $brand[$value[21]]['products'][]=$value[1];
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_unique() could do that for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Can you please elaborate for the benefit of OP? Possibly provide example code?